# YouTube video in fullscreen mode being cropped

Tags: browser, youtube

I have a phone Xiaomi Mi 9T with Android 9 and I have MIUI installed on it. My problem is that when watching videos on the mobile version of YouTube in fullscreen mode, videos are being cropped. Here is an example: YouTube video on my phone and PC.

On PC

[image]

On the phone in mobile version, you can see that the bottom part has been cropped.

[image]

I tried on Firefox and Chrome, it seems that every browser on my phone uses the same player, so videos are being cropped everywhere.

Also, if I use the desktop version of YouTube and open videos in fullscreen, then the player is cropped at the bottom.

On phone in fullscreen

[image]

Do you know how I can fix these?

Comment: Does this happen in the YouTube app as well? Did you try turning desktop mode on in Chrome for example?

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander It doesn't happen in Youtube app, but I don't like to use it for other reasons, I would like to browse youtube in Chrome. I did attach an image with desktop mode in Chrome (the third image): you can see that the video is not being cropped but the player is.

Comment: Did you try zooming in AND out? Could you share the URL with us? Sometimes you can change the URL to make the website think it's running from a computer.

Comment: Have you heard of OG YouTube maybe that'll work for you.

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander How do I zoom? I tried stretching with two fingers like an image, but it didn't zoom. Here is the link https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xebewT6lh2k&t=2s. This is the mobile version. It would be nice if there is a way to fix this on mobile version.

Comment: Settings -> accessability -> enable force zoom. youtube.com/watch?v=xebewT6lh2k&t=2s try this link, without the m. At the beginning.

Comment: Did it work? Or do you still need help?

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander I don't have enable force zoom. All my browsers use the same player when playing videos on youtube, I think I need to change the player. Is there a way?

Comment: Try adding this extension to Firefox. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/external-video-player/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you. Try using the Firefox browser, it worked for me.